# np.quantile with wrong calculation?

Tags: python, numpy

Under certain settings, np.quantile makes mistakes in determining the correct quantile. Is this a bug?

```
x = np.array([374, 358, 341, 355, 342, 334, 353, 346, 355, 344,
              349, 330, 352, 328, 336, 359, 361, 345, 324, 386,
              334, 370, 349, 327, 342, 354, 361, 354, 377, 324])

q = np.quantile(x, 0.25)

print(q)

print(len(x[x<=q]) / len(x))

print(len(x[x>=q]) / len(x))
```

Output:

```
337.25

0.26666666666666666

0.7333333333333333
```

0.73 means that only 73% of values are larger or equal than the determined quantile; by definition it should be >= 75%

Comment: according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) there is no standard definition of a quantile/percentile. But it also says that "For example, the 20th percentile is the value (or score) below which 20% of the observations may be found". So rather than looking at how many values are greater, you should probably look at how many are smaller than `q`. I'm not an expert in statistics though ;)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! @SamProell what you request is already in the question, with `print(len(x[x<=q]) / len(x))` ;)

Comment: @jeannej, i know! The point i was trying to make, is that numpy is correct in the stated example, if you look at how many values in `x` are smaller than `q`. Since `len(x[x<=q]) / len(x) = 0.2566` at least 25% of values lie below `q`.

Comment: @SamProell I'm sorry I don't get it. `len(x[x<=q]) / len(x) = 0.2666` so a bit more than `26%` of values lie below `q`, but how is it any different from saying that at least `73%` of values are larger (with the decimals short) ? There is still a problem as it is not `25%` and `75%` as expected here...

Comment: @jeannej, it's not different. The problem lies in the definition of the quantile. If you define the 25th percentile q to be the value for which at least 25 percent of values in the list are smaller than q (as is done in wikipedia), you cannot also expect at least 75% of values greater than q. Also, since there are 30 elements in the list, you cannot get exactly 25% or 75%.

Comment: @jeannej (and SamProell): The definition is not "smaller than" or "larger than", but "smaller or equal than" and "larger or equal than", therefore the sum of both fraction can be larger than 1. Therefore, there is a number that fulfills the definition in the described case, which is 366, the correct answer. My point is not, how to obtain that correct answer, but that the numpy function actually can produce a wrong result without checking it against the definition. With my post, I wanted to check, whether I made a logical mistake, and if not, make numpy programmers aware of the problem

Comment: @PepinoDoMar going back to the definition of quantiles in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile), i have to agree that 336 would be the correct solution for this specific case. If you haven't done so already, i'd suggest you open an issue on github. Still, i don't think this is necessarily a problem in the implementation rather than inconsistent definitions across and within sources. (once again, I am not an expert in statistics ;)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.1/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L3543-L3644

```
default value is linear
    interpolation : {'linear', 'lower', 'higher', 'midpoint', 'nearest'}
        This optional parameter specifies the interpolation method to
        use when the desired quantile lies between two data points
        ``i < j``:
            * linear: ``i + (j - i) * fraction``, where ``fraction``
              is the fractional part of the index surrounded by ``i``
              and ``j``.
            * lower: ``i``.
            * higher: ``j``.
            * nearest: ``i`` or ``j``, whichever is nearest.
            * midpoint: ``(i + j) / 2``.
```

If you select 'higher' you get what you want

Comment: not sure that 'higher' is really what Pepino wants, as you still don't get a 25%/75% distribution

Comment: And if not, then the method produces a wrong result, which is dangerous for users of the method... that is actually my main point. I know that I get the correct answer with np.quantile(x, 0.25, interpolation="lower") = 366.

Answer (score 1):

As @SamProell stated, there are different conventions to calculate centiles, as you can see [here with quartile's computing methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) (american way). Here we have an even number of data so let's stick to the first method and let's try to see how we would do it "by hand".

First, sort the data:

```
> x2=np.sort(x)
> print(x2)
array([324, 324, 327, 328, 330, 334, 334, 336, 341, 342, 342, 344, 345,
       346, 349, 349, 352, 353, 354, 354, 355, 355, 358, 359, 361, 361,
       370, 374, 377, 386])
```

Then divide the data in two halves:

```
> x2_low = x2[:int(len(x2)/2)]
array([324, 324, 327, 328, 330, 334, 334, 336, 341, 342, 342, 344, 345,
       346, 349])
> x2_up = x2[int(len(x2)/2):]
array([349, 352, 353, 354, 354, 355, 355, 358, 359, 361, 361, 370, 374,
       377, 386])
```

Finally find the median (i.e. the value cutting your data in half). Here lies a choice  as `len(x2_low)=15`. You could say that the median of x2_low is its 8th value (index 7 in python), then:

```
> q = x2_low[int(len(x2_low)/2)]
336
> len(x2_low[x2_low<q])
7
> len(x2_low[x2_low>q])
7
```

this is also what `np.median(x2_low)` would return, or even `q=np.percentile(x2,25,interpolation='lower')`. But you would still get:

```
> len(x[x<q])/len(x)
0.2333333333334
```

As your number of data is not a multiple of 4. Now it all depends on what you want to achieve, here are the results you can get for all interpolation parameter:

`linear`: default one, you got it in your question

`lower`: see above

`higher`:

```
> q=np.percentile(x,25,interpolation='higher')
341
> len(x[x>q])/len(x)
0.7
> len(x[x<q])/len(x)
0.26666666666666666
```

`nearest`:

```
> q=np.percentile(x,25,interpolation='nearest')
336
> len(x[x>q])/len(x)
0.7333333333333333
> len(x[x<q])/len(x)
0.23333333333333334
```

and finally `midpoint`:

```
> q=np.percentile(x,25,interpolation='midpoint')
> len(x[x>q])/len(x)
0.7333333333333333
> len(x[x<q])/len(x)
0.26666666666666666
```

It all depends on what you want to do with this afterwards. For more information on the different calculation methods, check for [numpy's documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html#numpy.quantile).

Comment: @SamProell For the correct definition you need to use "<=" and ">=" when you perform the test of the determined quantile. In this case np.quantile(x, 0.25, interpolation="lower") delivers the correct result, 366, where 26% are <= 366 and 76% are >= 366, therefore the correct result in this dataset. My point is, the standard version of this method (without "interpolation="lower"") delivers a wrong result. And "interpolation="lower") only works correct for p<0.5, for p>0.5, it again produces a wrong result (and one needs to use "interpolation="higher"").

Comment: @PepinoDoMar It is not a wrong result, but a different way to define quantile. The code works as intended, see the definition in `numpy` documentation. If the "lower" interpolation gives what you want, why would you consider that there is a bug in `numpy` ?

Comment: I might add that if there was only one way to define quantile calculation, `numpy` coders would not have bothered to implement different interpolation types ;)